# Assembly reference error (CS0234) when using System.Security.Cryptography in Xamarin Studio 6.1 on Mac OS X

Tags: c#, android, ios, macos, xamarin-studio

Running Xamarin Studio (Community) 6.1 (build 4963) on OS X El Capitan 10.11.5, I am trying to use RNGCryptoService in my solution (targets iOS and Android) for which I need to use the namespace System.Security.Cryptography. However, it seems like `using System.Security.Cryptography;` and then calling `RNGCryptoServiceProvider random = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();` somewhere in my code gives me the error.

> Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Cryptography' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Security'. Are you missing an assembly reference? (CS0234)

I tried to look for the System.Security.Cryptography package in the NuGet repositories (including the pre-release versions) but I did not find anything.

What am I missing? Where can I find the assembly reference?

Comment: You are trying to use this code directly in the Android or iOS project or a PCL project?

Comment: I'm new to Xamarin Studio on OS X. I started a project with Xamarin.Forms to let me develop the UI for both Android and iOS, so I presume it is a PCL project. The part of the code that I need the secure random number generator for is common to both platforms, so it is neither Android nor iOS specific.

Comment: Both Xamarin iOS and Android support the [RNGCryptoServiceProvider  class](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/available-assemblies/) however PCL projects do not. JAL's suggestion to use PCLCrypto library is a good approach if you need a pure PCL implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the [System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms) package to use `RNGCryptoServiceProvider`.  Install that with NuGet v 3.4 or later:

```
> PM Install-Package System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms
```

You may also need to modify your `project.json` file to make this package a dependency of dotnet5.4 and not a global dependency to stop the compiler from complaining about duplicate class declarations.

Follow up: It looks like System.Security.dll is not supported on Xamarin.iOS or Android.  As an alternative, you might have some luck with Jeffrey Stedfast's fork of the Bouncy Castle cryptography library [bc-csharp](https://github.com/jstedfast/bc-csharp/tree/vs2010) for use with Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS.

Another option might be to use the [PCLCrypto](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PCLCrypto/) library with [this helper class](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/112226/#Comment_112226) and workaround for NuGet.

Comment: The System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms NuGet package does not currently work with Xamarin.

Comment: @MattWard then I think you may be out of luck.  I don't see another way to use this dependency.

Comment: I concur with @MattWard - so is this a problem for which a bug report needs to be filed?

Comment: @xtremebytes is it a problem with one of the dependencies?  The NuGet package page says there are no dependencies for MonoAndroid, MonoTouch and Xamarin.  Maybe the package relies on some .NET code which isn't available with Xamarin?  Have you considered looking at the source code of the package and porting over the specific classes, decoupling them from the .NET runtime?

Comment: @xtremebytes Ah I think I found the issue.  It doesn't look like System.Security.dll is supported on mobile.  I've updated my answer with another potential library which might help you.  I'll keep digging...

Comment: @JAL I suppose the `System.Security.Cryptography` is actually pure .NET but I do not understand why that should not be supported by Xamarin. It contains classes, e.g., the secure random number generator that is vital.

Comment: @xtremebytes Added another secure crypto library which might help.

Comment: @JAL - The System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms NuGet package has no assemblies for Xamarin.iOS nor Xamarin.Android. Which indicates that Xamarin supports that assembly in its framework assemblies or at least will at some point, if it does not currently. The newer NuGet packages that target NuGet 3 need support in the build tools so the assemblies are referenced at compile time. Currently the Xamarin build tools do not do this which is why these NuGet packages are not supported. At least not yet.

Comment: @JAL - The PCLCrypto NuGet package looks like the way to go if a PCL project is being used.

Comment: Thanks, both. I did try using PCLCrypto package and it did not work for me, so may be my project is not PCLCrypto? If that is the case then, according to this [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/available-assemblies/), I should already have access to what I need?

Comment: Where can I check if my project is PCLCrypto and where can I change that, instead of starting a new project?

Comment: @JAL I forgot to mention that I was aware of the bc-csharp, but I was inclined to use the Xamarin stuff. Nonetheless, good suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: @xtremebytes you can learn more about PCL vs Shared Projects [here](https://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/sharing_code_options/).

Comment: @xtremebytes I'm still looking for an alternate but if Matt recommends PCLCrypto (and he works for Xamarin), I'd go with that.  Let me know if you need anything else before awarding the bounty.

Comment: @JAL thank you very much indeed. I'll award the bounty, but if you find an alternative, do suggest in the comments anyway.

Comment: @MattWard has there been any progress, or is there any plan for making the System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms work with Xamarin? PCLCrypto is an option but it seems like for almost any crypto operation, I have to look for how it is done in PCLCrypto. I wonder why there are no assemblies for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android while cryptographic algorithms are basic things that should be there.

Comment: @xtremebytes - The latest Xamarin build tools now support building projects that use project.json files. Using the System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms NuGet package should now resolve this NuGet package reference to the underlying platform implementation. I ran a quick test and you seem to be able to use types from assemblies that are from this particular NuGet package in a Xamarin.iOS project, at least in the simulator. However I have not done extensive testing.

Comment: @MattWard that sounds good but I do not think I understood how you got there. I still consider myself pretty basic with Xamarin. I'm using Xamarin Studio but last time I tried (over this weekend), I could not add the NuGet package System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms to the Xamarin Forms project.

Comment: @MattWard according to this (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/available-assemblies/), assemblies are available for System.Security.Cryptography in System.dll for iOS and Android. I will try this evening again.

Comment: @MattWard, here's what I get when I try to add that NuGet package to my project.
`Could not install package 'System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms 4.2.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile78', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
`

Comment: @xtremebytes - Looks like I only tried it a platform specific project not a PCL project. The System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms does not have any PCL or .NET Standard folders in the lib folder which I believe is why you cannot install it into any PCL project.

Comment: @MattWard is that going to be changed so that I can add it to a PCL project? Not having access to standard cryptographic libraries is a big show stopper.

Comment: Looking into this a bit more the System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms has .NET Standard 1.3 assemblies and above. PCL projects only support up to [.NET Standard 1.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library) so it looks like you will not be able to  use the System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms NuGet package in a PCL project. Xamarin Studio does not currently have good support for creating .NET Standard projects.

Comment: @MattWard, so that is a big problem. This means that developers needing the standard crypto libraries from .NET will not be able to access them. I may need to find an alternative to Xamarin for projects needing crypto stuff.

Comment: @xtremebytes - Possible workarounds include using the PCLCrypto NuGet package or using a .NETStandard project instead of a PCL project. Xamarin will be adding support for .NETStandard projects, possibly available in the next alpha release, but the current stable release does not have good support for it.